# Никто не знал, как следует правильно делать презентацию, чтобы она понравилась шефу, разве что снова спросить у Анны

Tags: синтаксис

> Никто не знал, как следует правильно делать презентацию, чтобы она
>   понравилась шефу, **разве что снова спросить у Анны.**

Разобрала все части этого предложения, но у меня есть трудности с фрагментом *разве что снова спросить у Анны*. Не могу определить вид этого придаточного предложения и назвать сказуемое. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Корректный вариант предложения:

Вряд ли мы сейчас узнаем, как следует правильно делать презентацию,  **разве что снова спросить у Анны**.

Союз РАЗВЕ ЧТО близок к союзу ЕСЛИ ТОЛЬКО со значением ограничения, но при этом он имеет еще дополнительное значение предположения.

Поэтому это придаточное **с ограничительно-уступительным предположительным значением** (частный вид уступительных предложений).

Действие в главной части определяется как в целом невозможное (затруднительное), но можно предположить его осуществление при определенном условии.

**Из словаря:**

**РАЗВЕ ЧТО** разг. Употребляется при выражении предположения, соответствуя по значению сл.: может быть, если только, вот разве только. [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/233712/Разве](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/233712/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1):

Я не лингвист, так что мнение мое воспринимайте критически.

Не думаю, что *разве что снова спросить у Анны* — придаточное. Фраза очень разговорная и не очень корректная.

Вот пример корректного употребления "разве что", которое связывает две части предложения:

> Сиденья замечаний не вызвали, разве что материал обивки сзади и по бокам несколько простоват. [Александр Будкин. Плащ тореадора (2003) // «За рулем», 2003.05.15]

Здесь "разве что" можно заменить на *но* или  *за исключением того, что*.

Ваше предложение звучало бы гораздо луче в таком виде:

**Никто не знал, что делать, чтобы презентация понравилась шефу, разве что снова спросить у Анны.**

Не знали, что делать, а исключением того, чтобы спросить у Анны (это они знали).

А в исходном виде "Не знал как правильно делать презентацию, з исключением того, чтобы спросить у Анны" — некорректно. Спрашивать у Анны — не способ делать презентацию.

В исходном виде слова "разве что снова спросить у Анны" семантически оторваны и представляют собой отдельное предложение "Может снова спросить у Анны?"

Поэтому я бы писал так:

**Никто не знал, как следует правильно делать презентацию, чтобы она понравилась шефу.  Разве что снова спросить у Анны?**

Или как БСП:

**Никто не знал, как следует правильно делать презентацию, чтобы она понравилась шефу —   разве что снова спросить у Анны?**